# How to use 'persevere'?

Tags: prepositions, translation

I need to translate a sentence and I cannot figure out a good way to do so. Can I use the word 'persevere' like this, or are there better ways?

> Vincas consistently deepens his knowledge, he is not afraid of any difficulties that may arise, but perseveres **by means of** determination and work.

Do I need to change the highlighted part to anything else, or is it good as-is?

Comment: It is wordy, but grammatically correct. I would say "but perseveres by determination and work." Saying "hard work" instead of "work" might flow a little better with the context. You also have a comma splice in the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! I agree with @AmericanLuke - you can replace the first comma with a semicolon; you can pare down the sentence, or make a new sentence from the phrase between the commas.

Comment: Maybe this is just me, but I don't feel that it's possible to persevere *by means of* or *by* or *by dint of* anything. I don't think it's a grammatical constraint, however, but a semantic one: you persevere simply by persevering, there's no other intermediate quality or action by which you persevere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence: "Vincas consistently deepens his knowledge, he is not afraid of any difficulties that may arise, but perseveres by means of determination and work." (23 words)

There are probably 50 or more ways of translating your sentence, though into *what* language it is being translated is a concern, and the particular tongue might narrow your choices. Nevertheless, I kind of like

> "Vincas consistently deepens his knowledge and is not afraid of any difficulties. By dint of determination and hard work he perseveres." (21)

I like "by dint of," though it is a bit old fashioned, perhaps. Then there's

> "Vincas consistently deepens his knowledge and confronts any difficulties which may arise; by determination and hard work he perseveres." (19)

What about

> "Despite difficulties, Vincas consistently deepens his knowledge, and through determination and hard work he perseveres." (15)

And last,

> "Vincas consistently deepens his knowledge, confronts difficulties head-on, and perseveres with determination and hard work." (15)

Comment: Re: "into *what* language it is being translated is a concern": I assume it is being translated into English. That is -- I assume the OP's sentence is the result of translation, not the source.